# I'm new to C, having some issues with scanf and my variable equaling 0

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

The problem is that no matter what, my depth either equals 0, or it shows it equaling whatever you put in with the scan, but stills acts like it is 0 later. I tried messing around with the formatting a bit but to no avail. Thanks!

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double depth;
    printf("Please enter the current depth in Kilometers.");
    scanf("%d", &depth);
    printf("The depth is %f \n", depth);
    double celcius = (10* depth + 20);
    printf("The temperature in celcius  is %f \n", celcius);
    double fahrenheit = (1.8*celcius+31);
    printf("The temperature in fahrenheit  is %f \n", fahrenheit);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should warn you that `%d` isn't the correct format specifiers for double. `%lf` is actually the correct one for `scanf`, while you can use `%f` with `printf`. I would advice you to compile with one (or all of them) of the command listed above :

- -Wall
- -Wextra
- -pedantic

You can find more information about gcc warnings [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Also have a read here :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: The suggestion to do "%1f" did not seem to change anything. Is there a fatal error somewhere else as well?

Comment: @Wearin It's not "1" it's a lowercase L

Comment: Oh wow, I feel dumb. Thanks man!

Comment: @Wearin No problem. If this really helped you consider up voting my answer

Answer (score 2):

You have *undefined behavior* as you read and parse the input as an *integer* (the `"%d"` format reads integers) and store that integer in a floating-point variable. Integer and floating point values are not stored in the same format on computers.

You need to use the `"%lf"` [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format:

```
scanf("%lf", &depth);
```

Comment: The suggestion to do "%1f" did not seem to change anything. Is there a fatal error somewhere else as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch in `scanf`: you specify `%d` but pass a pointer to a `double` where `scanf` expects a pointer to `int`.

Fix the code this way:

```
scanf("%lf", &depth);
```

There is another error, albeit non fatal: the conversion from Celcius to  Fahrenheit is incorrect, it should read:

```
double fahrenheit = 1.8 * celcius + 32;
```

Comment: The suggestion to do "%1f" did not seem to change anything. Is there a fatal error somewhere else as well?

Comment: @Wearin: it did not change anything because you mistyped it, it is `"%lf"` as in Lima Foxtrot, not `"%1f"`.